# Magento 1.9 webp images rewrite htaccess

Tags: magento-1.9, htaccess

I can't figure out why my htaccess won't rewrite urls to webp images, only images that are on **skin** directory get served as webp.

https://domain/skin/frontend/theme/test/images/image.png will be served as webp image from
https://domain/skin/frontend/theme/test/images/image.webp

If it is a wysiwyg image in /media/wysiwyg/ directory it won't be serverd as webp..

https://domain/media/wysiwyg/pags/images/en_image02_2x.jpg however exactly as skins directory there is webp image with same file name....

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} image/webp
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (?i)(.*)(\.jpe?g|\.png)$
   RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.webp -f
   RewriteRule (.+)\.(jpe?g|png)$ $1.webp [L,T=image/webp,R]
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
     Header append Vary Accept env=REDIRECT_accept
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_mime.c>
     AddType image/webp .webp
 </IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem and after struggling I found out that there was a .htaccess in the media folder of magento..
I think you just need to to add the code inside and it works ! Hope this help